# Inserting a date field with soap API

Tags: soap-api, date

I was trying to use Soap API to update DatedConversionRate, as that salesforce object does not allow the use of Dml. I am using advanced currency management. How do I avoid the clash of the requirements for the date (namely ISO 8601 using the '-' character)?

```
Http h = new Http ();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest ();
req.setEndpoint(URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v59.0/sobjects/DatedConversionRate');
req.setMethod('POST');
string body = '{ "IsoCode" : "' + datum.iso + '", "ConversionRate" : ' + datum.rate + ', "StartDate" : ' + datum.StartDate + ' }';
system.debug(body);
req.setBody(body);
req.setHeader('Authorization' , 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId()); 
req.setHeader('Content-Type' , 'application/json'); 
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
system.debug(res.getBody());
```

Below is the first of the two debug lines

```
16:39:37:267 USER_DEBUG [134]|DEBUG|{ "IsoCode" : "EUR", "ConversionRate" : 0.9137426900584795, "StartDate" : 2023-12-20 00:00:00 }
```

And this is the second

```
16:39:37:395 USER_DEBUG [139]|DEBUG|[{"message":"Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [line:1, column:80]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON doesn't have a "native" date type. It has to be a string with quotes around it. Never write your own JSON, as it's easy to get wrong. I recommend using at minimum a combination of Map/List as needed, demonstrated below. Alternatively, consider using a wrapper class, also shown below.

```
String body = JSON.serialize(
  new Map<String, Object> {
    'IsoCode' => datum.iso,
    'ConversionRate' => datum.rate,
    'StartDate' => datum.StartDate
  }
);
```

```
class Wrapper {
  String IsoCode;
  Decimal ConversionRate;
  Date StartDate;
  Wrapper(String Iso, Decimal rate, Date start) {
   isocode = iso;
   conversionrate = rate;
   startdate = start;
  }
}
// ... some time later
String body = JSON.serialize(new Wrapper(datum.iso, datum.rate, datum.startdate));
```

Comment: will serializing in this manner prevent the date from having a - in the date output?

Comment: @zoboso No. The `-` are supposed to be there. However, what you're missing are the `"`. Encoding a date should look like this: `{ "StartDate": "2023-12-21" }`. This is why I suggest letting the framework do the work for you.

Comment: I copied your map code and it worked, thank you for the help.